# error: called object ‘fopen’ is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c, header, stdio

Really odd error I am getting at the moment,

In my #include section, I have `#include <stdio.h>` which according to the man page for fopen is required

```
"SYNOPSIS
       #include <stdio.h>"
```

I am also using fdopen which is in the stdio.h in the same code as well and it is working

```
fp = fdopen(fdes, "r+");
```

The error points to the following code

```
fout = fopen(fname, "wb");
```

With the full error being

```
getFileCli.c:94:12: error: called object ‘fopen’ is not a function or function pointer
     fout = fopen(fname, "wb");
            ^
getFileCli.c:22:8: note: declared here
  FILE *fopen;
```

now if I use the code from the fopen header of `FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);` in the main section it works perfectly fine.

I ran a locate on my system

```
locate stdio.h
/usr/include/stdio.h
/usr/include/c++/4.9/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20.2/CORE/nostdio.h
```

So I have it, any reason why the include is not working?

Comment: You declared a variable `fopen` of type `FILE*`. Why?

Comment: Reduce your code to `#include <stdio.h>` plus `int main(void) { FILE *fp = fopen("fixed-name", "wb"); return (fp != 0); }` or thereabouts. Do you still get the error? If not, add code back until you do; or start with your code and eliminate chunks until you have a minimal version that reproduces your problem. You'll be creating an MCVE ([MCVE]). But the compiler is telling you the problem, as [tkausl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1080064/tkausl) [pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313859/error-called-object-fopen-is-not-a-function-or-function-pointer#comment65960298_39313859).

Comment: Don't attempt to declare standard functions in your source files.  Standard functions should only be declared in the standard headers and you should use them.  In your own code, functions defined outside the current source file should have a header that declares them, and that header should be used in both the files that use the functions and in the file that defines them (a consistency check).  Functions defined for use only in the current file should be `static` and declared or defined before they are used.

Comment: @tkausl, that was it, I removed the FILE *fopen;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you compiler tries to tell you, you declared `fopen` to be a variable of type `FILE*`:

```
getFileCli.c:22:8: note: declared here
  FILE *fopen;
```

And since your variable is neither a function nor a function-pointer, you can't *call* it:

```
getFileCli.c:94:12: error: called object ‘fopen’ is not a function or function pointer
     fout = fopen(fname, "wb");
            ^
```

---

To fix it, remove the declaration `FILE *fopen;` in line 22 or rename the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to write `FILE *fout;` instead of `FILE *fopen;`